# Raspberry Pi using Python to mkdir

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I want to download all the pictures from a website using Python. I already have the title of the HTML file, so I use `os.mkdir()` to create a folder, but the title contains Chinese. When the following code is executed on Raspberry Pi (OS: Debian), there is an exception:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 20-38: ordinal not in range(128)

```
try:
    os.mkdir(path)
except:
    print "create folder failed"
    continue
```

Everything is fine if I run the code on my Mac.

I googled the problem and tried the code below, but it's not working.

```
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

Update:

I've changed my code a lot, and read some articles about unicode, utf-8 .etc. But everytime I run the code on Raspberry Pi , it crushed. Then I installed Debian OS (which is what I installed on my Raspberry Pi) on a PC, run the code on it, everything is fine.

So the problem is actually not caused by code, but by SSH.

If I run the code directly on the Debian PC in desktop enviroment, it's ok. If I login to the shell from my Mac using SSH, and run the code , there will be an exception says "Unicode...." something like that.

I think it's caused by environment variables, I'll try to figure it out tomorrow and thank you guys :-)

Comment: `setdefaultencoding` works rather with `print` or `write` - try `os.mkdir( path.encode('utf-8') )`

Comment: Wow it's working, thanks. But it's so annoying to change code. Is there a way to make it work like on my Mac ?

Comment: try `print  sys.getfilesystemencoding()` to see what you get. Maybe if you set environment variable `LANG` in Debian then you will not need to use `encode()`. Check in bash `echo $LANG` too.

Comment: @furas make that into an answer - it is a better ones than the ones suggested so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `r` or `u` prefix before your directory name, like

```
>>> import os
>>> os.mkdir(r'文件夹')
>>> os.mkdir(u'文件夹')
```

and it will create 'xxx/文件夹/' for me.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`setdefaultencoding` works rather with `print` or `write` - try `os.mkdir( path.encode('utf-8') )`

-

BTW: try `print sys.getfilesystemencoding()` - if you get something different than `utf8` than maybe you should set environment variable `LANG` in Bash. Check in Bash `echo $LANG`. If you get something without `utf8` try `export LANG=en_GB.utf8` in Bash before you run python script without `encode()`. If it will work you can put `export LANG=en_GB.utf8` in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` or probably `/etc/profile`

Search more about `locale` and `locales` in `raspberry`

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I know what is wrong :-)

The only thing should be done is just to set the `LC_CTYPE` environment variable to `"***.UTF-8"`

I installed Debian in English on a PC , Debian in Chinese on another PC. I have a vps(Ubuntu in English), and I have a Mac(Mac OS X in English). This is what I got
[image]

As you can see, when the `LC_CTPPE` is `"***.UTF-8"`, I can input Chinese and the shell can show Chinese. But when it's something else, my program will crush.

Summary:

1. If the code can run normally on your computer, but not on another computer, it may be caused by the environment variable(s).
2. If the `LC_CTYPE` is like `"*.UTF-8"` , everything is fine. Be careful is't not `*.UTF-8` , it's `"*.UTF-8"`, pay attention to the quotes. Don't know whether it's a bug but just `UTF-8` without quotes will not work.
3. Some app such as iTerm will set the environment variables for you when you login to another computer, sometime it will cause problems.

Thank you all the same.

Update:
Here is my opinion, maybe it's wrong.

If the `LC_CTYPE` is `UTF-8` without quotes, the OS will not understand it , so OS uses ASCII. When there is a word in Chinese, python will try to decode it to unicode and there is no problem. But when there is a `print`, python will try to encode the word to `LC_CTYPE` to print it to screen. If the word's unicode is greater than 127, DUANG!DUANG!DUANG , there is an exception.

Answer (score -1):

Probably you are working with Python 2, try adding the following code at the very top of you script and see if it will work:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

and don't forget to remove your 2 lines with `sys`.

This will enable unicode strings everywhere in your script by default, so any string gotten as result or defined explicitly (even without `u`) like `s="string"` will be unicode string and therefore will support Chinese characters.

Comment: Care to explain when downvoting, why am I wrong and my suggestion is not an option?